# Finding the main parent after sorting in a multiplication process

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have

```
list1={10, 3, 25, 6, 28, 21, 17, 22, 1, 24, 16, 7, 9, 15, 2, 18, 5, 27, 30, 8}
list2={17, 11, 24, 22, 20, 27, 1, 21, 25, 30, 2, 18, 9, 29, 10, 23, 8, 26, 15, 28}
```

I want to create a list of multiply a member of list1 to a member of list2 in the order: `10*28, 3*15, 25*26, 6*8 ....` for example with `Do[list1[[i]].list2[[21 - i]], {i, 1, 20}]]]` After that I want to sort the last result from smaller to larger. and determine the first of the final list

The psudo-code:

```
First[Sort[Do[list1[[i]].list2[[21 - i]], {i, 1, 20}],, #1 < #2 &]]
```

I can write it with define another (third) list for `Do[list1[[i]].list2[[21 - i]]`, But how can I write this code without defining third list. and how can I recognize the first element of the sorted final list (which is determined with `First`, is relate to which `i` (which element of the list1)

Comment: `First@Sort[list1*Reverse@list2]`.

Comment: OK, And how can I find the relation of the first element of the sorted and list1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
First@Sort[{Times @@ #, #} & /@ Transpose[{list1, Reverse@list2}]]
(* {15, {15, 1}} *)
```

The first number is the minimum of the multiplications (15), which was obtained from multiplying (15) from `list1` by (1) from `list2`.
The following:

```
Sort[{Times@##, ##} & @@@ Transpose[{list1, Reverse@list2}]] // First
```

also performs the same thing.

If you want the parent only

```
Ordering[list1 Reverse@list2, 1]
(*14*)
```

gives you the position of the parent on `list1`. And

```
list1[[Ordering[list1 Reverse@list2, 1]]]
(* {15} *)
```

gives you its value.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer, both your answer and March's answer are so fruitful. really I don't know which answer should be accepted.

Comment: @mr.0093. It doesn't matter.

Comment: @mr.0093, if you're having a hard time picking between two equally excellent answers, toss a coin… :)

Comment: @Guess, It is a good comment, thanks

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I believe `RandomChoice[{"ans1", "ans2"}]` is more appropriate

Comment: @bel, silly me, you're right, of course! :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a somewhat verbose and strange way of getting your answer:

```
Function[{x}, {#, list1[[#]], x[[#]]} & @@ Ordering[x, 1]] @ Times[list1, Reverse@list2]
```

`Times[list1, Reverse@list2]` gets your third list.

This function:

```
Function[{x}, {#, list1[[#]], x[[#]]} & @@ Ordering[x, 1]]
```

takes `Times[list1, Reverse@list2]` as the argument `x`. `Ordering[x, 1]` returns a list containing the index of the smallest value of the list `x` as a list. Then,

```
{#, list1[[#]], x[[#]]} & @@ Ordering[x, 1]
```

returns a list of three elements: the first is the index at which the smallest value in the third list appears, the second is the value of `list1` appearing at that index, and the third is the value of the third list (which is the smallest value in this third list).

Therefore,

```
list1={10, 3, 25, 6, 28, 21, 17, 22, 1, 24, 16, 7, 9, 15, 2, 18, 5, 27, 30, 8};
list2={17, 11, 24, 22, 20, 27, 1, 21, 25, 30, 2, 18, 9, 29, 10, 23, 8, 26, 15, 28};

Function[{x}, {#, list1[[#]], x[[#]]} & @@ Ordering[x, 1]] @ Times[list1, Reverse@list2]
(* {14, 15, 15} *)
```

**Simplification if you only want the "parent"**

If all you want is the value of `list1` that makes the smallest value of the third list, you can do

```
Part[list1, First@Ordering@Times[list1, Reverse@list2]]
(* 15 *)
```

or

```
list1[[First@Ordering@Times[list1, Reverse@list2]]]]
```

or, using `Infix` notation,

```
list1 ~Part~ First@Ordering@Times[list1, Reverse@list2]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and your explanation, both your answer and Belisarius's answer are so good. really I don't know which answer should be accepted.

Comment: however your explanation was so good to me but based on Guess's comment I tossed a coin!

Answer (score 5):

I notice no one is using an association to map to positions nor allowing the sort to use a one-element heap instead of building up an entire sorted array ...

```
PositionIndex[#] @@ 
    TakeSmallestBy[#, Times @@ # &, 1] & 
[
    Transpose[{list1, Reverse@list2}]
]
```

In the example, the result is `{14}`, the index of `15` in `list1` that gets paired with `1` in `list2`.  Perhaps more easily understood (but doing essentially the same thing):

```
PositionIndex[#][
   Sort[
       #,
       OrderedQ[{#1[[1]] #1[[2]], #2[[1]] #2[[2]]}] &
   ][[1]]
] & [
    Transpose[{list1, Reverse@list2}]
]
```